# how to fix wordpress database that cannot be export and then imported

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am new to wordpress. I trying to backup a local wordpress installation to move it to a shared host.  But when I backup the database using phpmyadmin Export to SQL file and then try to import it -- it fails reading in the wp_options table.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have not had your exact issues but something similar, best I can tell from reading between your lines:) Solved it by using a WordPress plugin called WP Migrate DB.

You can read more about it [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)

The free version was all I needed and actually did more than needed. You will still need PHPMyadmin (or similar) on destination server to import the SQL file saved to your local drive.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Hi Woody, Is it possible to export just the database with this tool?

Comment: It might actually be easier for you to use a different plugin that is not as advanced. Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-database-backup/, install, activate and look in tools menu.

Comment: I tried WP Migrate DB.  It created the file, but failed trying to import it into phpmyadmin. :(   Thanks for trying.

Comment: Sorry it did not work for you. If you are using localhost (like wamp) to develop your site could be issue. Best to migrate from localhost to server with tool/plugin like "Duplicator" @ https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: Yes, I am using wamp on my computer to develop the site.  I bought Updraft Plus Premium to migrate.  And it performed the migration, but failed with the database error. Because the database created was faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite enough information... but Ill try help.

You could:

- Try exporting it in a different format.
- Open the export file and manually search for errors.
- Look for any errors while in phpmyadmin

If you can, post the table.

Comment: How would I post the table?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help!

Comment: Something like this

Comment: Haha nevermind it screwed up. Hope you figure it out :)

Comment: I posted it to FileDropper. Here is the link: https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=df46e2a185e451230ba9a8dfcbf02af6

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to my problem on Stack Overflow. [Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855676/error-while-importing-mysql-dump-in-mysql-5-7/)

The solution was to upgrade my version of phpmyadmin from 4.5.5.1 to 4.6.5.1.
This allowed the database to be properly exported and imported.  Thank you to those who help along the way!